# Binomial coefficient for real values

Tags: java, binomial-coefficients

I'm looking for an efficient Java implementation of Binomial coefficients ( choose(n,k) ) defined for all real numbers n and integers k, ie defined as:

[image]

Comment: Check out the [Wikipedia entry] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: All "real numbers `n`". I hope you realize that implies emitting the [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: @Mystical, the denominator 'k' is integer, thus there is no gamma implied.  Even though it's efficient unless 'k' is small.  For small 'k' it may be more efficient to simply iterate the few multiplications and divisions, alternating, starting from the lower end to keep the error low...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With usage of [Apache Commons Math 3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html#gamma%28double%29):

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.special.Gamma;

/**
 * Binomial coefficient for real numbers - the number of ways of picking y
 * unordered outcomes from x possibilities
 *
 * @see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html
 *
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @return binomial coefficient to be generalized to noninteger arguments
 */
public double binomial(double x, double y) {
    double res = Gamma.gamma(x + 1) / (Gamma.gamma(y + 1) * Gamma.gamma(x - y + 1));
    if(Double.isNaN(res)){
        return 0.0;
    }
    return res;
}
```

So for input `binomial(0.5, 1.0)` you should get `0.5`, like in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%280.5%2C+1%29)

```
binomial(2.5, 3) = 0.3125
binomial(2.0, 3) = 0.0
binomial(1.5, 3) = -0.0625
```